# Need to extract strings from text file to use as variables

Tags: batch-file

I need to pull out specific text to go into variables, but I also need to get rid of characters.

I pull reg information for mapped drives and clean up the file. using FINDSTR /v I get the following text file.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network\h]
"RemotePath"="\\\\server\\folder1\\folder2"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network\i]
"RemotePath"="\\\\server2\\folder1"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network\j]
"RemotePath"="\\\\server3\\folder1"
```

I need to pull the drive letter and the RemotePath but need to also remove the extra backslashes so that these variables can be used to remap on a new computer.

Comment: Just a quick example: `for /F "delims=[]" %G IN ("[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network\h]") DO echo %~nxG` would output **h**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a demo for processing the **ANSI encoded** registry data in the file `RegistryData.txt`:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if not exist "RegistryData.txt" goto EndBatch
set "DriveLetter="
for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=[]=" %%I in ("RegistryData.txt") do (
    if "%%~I" == "RemotePath" (
        set "FolderPath=%%~J"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo Drive !DriveLetter!: mapped to "!FolderPath:\\=\!"
        endlocal
        set "DriveLetter="
    ) else for /F "tokens=3 delims=\" %%# in ("%%I") do set "DriveLetter=%%#"
)
:EndBatch
endlocal
```

The outer **FOR** loop processes one line after the other from the registry data file. It splits up each line into two substrings using the square brackets and the equal sign as string delimiters. The first substring (token) is assigned to specified loop variable `I` and the second substring to next but one loop variable `J` according to the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) if there is a second substring at all.

The registry key (= drive letter) with full path is assigned to loop variable `I` for the lines starting with the delimiter `[` and ending with the delimiter `]`. Such a line is processed further by the inner **FOR** loop which processes the string assigned to loop variable `I` by splitting it up into substrings using `\` as string delimiter and assigning the third substring to specified loop variable `#`. That string value is assigned to the environment variable `DriveLetter`.

The string `"RemovePath"` with the double quotes is assigned to loop variable `I` by the outer **FOR** for the lines with registry string value `RemovePath` and the remote folder path with the double quotes to loop variable `J` which could even contain `[` or `]` or `=` one or more times because of `*` after `tokens=1` means do not further split up the line into substrings after the first substring.

The folder path is assigned with the surrounding double quotes removed to the environment variable `FolderPath`. Then [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled as required to reference the string values of the environment variables `DriveLetter` and `FolderPath` defined inside the command block being parsed completely by `cmd` before execution of outer **FOR** loop at all.

The drive letter and the folder path are output with **ECHO** using delayed expansion with replacing all occurrences of two backslashes by a single backslash in folder path.

Then the command **ENDLOCAL** is used to restore previous execution environment with delayed expansion disabled again which is necessary for folder paths in registry data containing one or more exclamation marks.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`